# Voltdb alive nodes throw an exception when executing "sqlcmd" after a node of a 3 node cluster with Ksafe 1 is shut down

Tags: voltdb

I have deployed a two site environment with a three node cluster of voltdb in each site with Ksafe=1. Clusters are configured with XCDR replication. 
I have performed a failover test, I have shut down the VM of one of the nodes of the cluster) and apparently the log does not throw any error but when I try to connect through the "sqlcmd" in the two alive nodes of that cluster I got the following error:

```
$ sqlcmd
org.voltdb.client.ProcCallException: Server is shutting down.
        at org.voltdb.client.ClientImpl.internalSyncCallProcedure(ClientImpl.java:481)
        at org.voltdb.client.ClientImpl.callProcedureWithClientTimeout(ClientImpl.java:320)
        at org.voltdb.client.ClientImpl.callProcedure(ClientImpl.java:256)
        at org.voltdb.utils.SQLCommand.loadStoredProcedures(SQLCommand.java:1253)
        at org.voltdb.utils.SQLCommand.mainWithReturnCode(SQLCommand.java:1567)
        at org.voltdb.utils.SQLCommand.main(SQLCommand.java:1626)
SQL Command :: localhost:21212
1> 

1> select count(*) from table1;

Server is shutting down
```

Does anyone know why if Ksafety=1 Voltdb throws this exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VoltDB here. If you have a 3 node Kfactor=1 cluster, shutting down one VM server and thus one node should not cause the entire cluster to shut down.

The fact that it is apparently shutting down in slow motion like this is indicative of some kind of draining process (such as the dr_overflow, since you are using XDCR). We usually see these extended draining processes on manual shutdowns, not crashes.

We would have to see the logs to know for sure what is happening. If you are a customer, you can email support@voltdb.com with the log files. If not, you can email sales@voltdb.com.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. The user had a script that was triggered when shutting down the VM. This script issued a voltdb shutdown command that brought down the whole cluster.